# Slick 3 with H2 database count issue

Tags: scala, count, h2, slick-3.0

We are using Slick 3 with Scala and H2 database. 
Versions:

- Slick - `3.0.1`
- H2 driver - `1.4.188`
- Scala - `2.11.7`

We want to get number of rows in the table. Code snippet looks like:

```
db.run(Tables.MyTable.length.result)
```

Our configuration looks like:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

val jdbcDriver = "org.h2.Driver"
val profile = slick.driver.H2Driver
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:myDBname")
```

When we run this `db.run` thingy we are keep getting errors like:

```
Failure(java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem:myDBname)
```

If we remove `length` from `db.run` command everything works fine. We tried also with `size` instead of `length`. The same issue. We also tried to bumped the versions of Slick (to `3.0.3` and also to `3.1.1`) and/or of H2 driver (to `1.4.191`) but the issue remains.

Funny fact is that either `length` and `size` work with PostgreSQL database (driver).

Any ideas or XPs with that issue?

Best

Comment: Hey man how's going. I'm not 100% sure but I'm guessing that the database you are creating is in memory (because of the `mem` in the url), if so your db is destroyed every time the connection si closed and actually that piece of code cannot find any db, try to use `jdbc:h2:mem:myDBname;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` as url after creating the database, this will avoid destroying it. In your stack trace you should see that it's failing on connection, removing `length.run` works because it's not actually calling the invoker.

Comment: Hi Ende! Thanks for fast feedback. We tried with adding DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to driver property. Still the same problem.

Comment: Then my next guess would be that you have to pass in the driver manually `Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:myDBname", driver = "org.h2.Driver")`, I could reproduce your issue when not passing in manually the driver, with this I only get a SQL exception because I don't have the table in my DB.

Comment: Now we have : `Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:myDBname;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", driver = "org.h2.Driver")` but still the same issue :(

Comment: And even if we try with `Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:myDBname;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", driver = "org.h2.Driver")` still the same issue.

Comment: I have managed to count the rows from a table with that, you can have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/EndeNeu/6b318f1a87d1f2ddf384), strange that it's not working for you.